# How do I stop users from booking in the past DateTime Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a booking lesson for users to book their instructors. The current problem I am facing is, How do I prevent the user from booking in the past? I have used DateTime.

Another problem is if the user sets the start DateTime, how to do I prevent the end DateTime from being less than the start DateTime?

I have not attempted it, may I have suggestions. The current code is showing how to stop double bookings.

**_form.hmtl.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@lesson) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lesson_start_date_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :lesson_start_date_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lesson_end_date_time %><br>
    <%= f.datetime_select :lesson_end_date_time %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Lesson.rb**

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base


belongs_to :user

validate :lessons_must_not_overlap

private

def lessons_must_not_overlap
   return if self
          .class
          .where.not(id: id)
          .where(user_id: user_id)
          .where('lesson_start_date_time < ? AND lesson_end_date_time > ?', lesson_end_date_time, lesson_start_date_time)
          .none?

   errors.add(:base, 'Overlapping lesson exists')
end

end
```

Comment: "Another problem is if the user sets the start DateTime, how to do I prevent the end DateTime from being less than the start DateTime?" Just create a simple custom validation where you check that `start_time < end_time`

Comment: "How do I prevent the user from booking in the past? I have used DateTime." Thats a no brainer - `start_time > Time.now`

Comment: @max Note: Always compare datetime with `Time.current` instead of `Time.now` to avoid TimeZone issues with the applications

Comment: I do not usually like to recommend additional dependencies but if you are going to be performing a lot of date/time validations the [`validates_timeliness`](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) gem might be very useful in your case and would allow you to use standard `ActiveModel` validation syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never should trust user input (so any changes in html are irrelevant)

You just need to validate  dates that come from user (keep validations as simple as possible, one validation should have one responsibility)

```
validates :lesson_end_date_time, :lesson_start_date_time, presence: true
validate :start_date_in_future, :dates_has_positive_length

private

def start_date_in_future
  return if lesson_start_date_time.blank?
  return if lesson_start_date_time >= Date.current
  errors.add(:lesson_start_date_time, :invalid)
end

def dates_has_positive_length
  return if lesson_end_date_time.blank? || lesson_start_date_time.blank?
  return if lesson_end_date_time >= lesson_start_date_time
  errors.add(:lesson_end_date_time, :invalid)
end
```

Comment: I did not notice you use times, not date, so use `Time.current` instead of `Date.current`

Comment: Also `lesson_started_at` looks prettier than `lesson_start_date_time`

Comment: @mikdiet but that implies past and saying the lesson_started_at tommorow is awkward. Past tense _at suffix works great for creation and update because they will always be in the past. I'd prefer lesson_start and lesson_end as they are more ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

Just add one more validation to check

1. `start date` is in past
2. `end_date` is less than `start_date`

Give this a try

```
validate :datetime_eligibility

private

#...

def datetime_eligibility
  # Check if `start_date` is less than `current time`
  if lesson_start_date_time < Time.current 
    errors.add(:base, "can't be in past")
  # Check if `end_date` is less than `start_date`
  elsif  lesson_end_date_time < lesson_start_date_time
    errors.add(:base, 'start date should be less than end date')
  end
end
```

**Note: Always compare datetime with `Time.current` instead of `Time.now` to avoid TimeZone issues with the applications**